# jquery multiple class selector

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors, click

I am trying to attach a click event handler on a button but it doesn't call the click event on the button. I guess I am using wrong selectors. Can anybody help me out?

The HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb20 submitForm" onclick="RemoveValidation()">Search</button>
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
$("#txtZip").keyup(function (event) {
    debugger;
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(".btn .submitForm").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between them to select element with both class,`.btn .submitForm` will search `.submitForm` within `.btn`.

```
$("#txtZip").keyup(function (event) {
    debugger;
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(".btn.submitForm").click();
        // ----^--- remove the space
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me the difference! :)

Comment: @HumaAli : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

or else you can use submit function.

```
<form id="form_id">
......
</form>

$("#txtZip").keyup(function (event) {
    debugger;
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#form_id").submit();
    }
});
```